# Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistance.room:testing:1.1.1

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to make an app in Android studio using the  Architecture Components Room and Lifecycles libraries but when I sync it, it gives me the error `Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistance.room:testing:1.1.1`

My code in the app `build.gradle` is:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "android.arch.persistance.room:testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifestyle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
```

Full project level `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

ext {
    roomVersion = '1.1.1'
    archLifecycleVersion = '1.1.1'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Failed to resolve: android.arch.persistance.room:testing:1.1.1

Open the **`build.gradle`** file for your project (not the ones for your app or module) and add the **`google()`** repository as shown below:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()

    }
}
```

You should use **`gradle:3.1.3`**

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
       }
```

After change ***`Clean-Rebuild and SYNC`*** with Internet.

**NOTE**

You should set **`lifecycle`** instead of **<s>lifestyle</s>**.

```
annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
```

Comment: @ToriHarris Do gradle on line mode.

Comment: I rebuilt it and now it gives me the error `Could not find android.arch.lifestyle:compiler:1.1.1.`

Comment: @ToriHarris use `annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"`